# What path would allow my Django app to see all of the installed modules?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-venv

I'm taking over a complex project. 5 engineers worked on this for years, but they have all left, and I'm trying to figure it out on my own.

I know they had this app previously running on Centos8, but Centos8 hit EOL in December, so I set up a new EC2 instance running Redhat8.

To get past some permission issues with various software, I'm running as root.

There was an install script that seemed to install a lot of software. If I do:

```
pip3 list
```

then I see:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
argcomplete          2.0.0
Babel                2.5.1
blueflow             2.7.3
certifi              2021.10.8
cffi                 1.11.5
chardet              3.0.4
click                8.0.4
cloud-init           21.1
clufter              0.77.1
configobj            5.0.6
cryptography         3.2.1
dbus-python          1.2.4
decorator            4.2.1
distlib              0.3.4
ethtool              0.14
file-magic           0.3.0
filelock             3.4.1
gpg                  1.13.1
html5lib             0.999999999
idna                 2.5
importlib-metadata   4.8.3
importlib-resources  5.4.0
iniparse             0.4
Jinja2               2.10.1
jsonpatch            1.21
jsonpointer          1.10
jsonschema           2.6.0
libcomps             0.1.16
lxml                 4.2.3
MarkupSafe           0.23
oauthlib             2.1.0
packaging            21.3
pcs                  0.10.10
perf                 0.1
pexpect              4.3.1
pip                  21.3.1
pipenv               2022.1.8
pipx                 1.0.0
platformdirs         2.4.0
ply                  3.9
prettytable          0.7.2
ptyprocess           0.5.2
pycparser            2.14
pycurl               7.43.0.2
PyGObject            3.28.3
pyinotify            0.9.6
PyJWT                1.6.1
pyOpenSSL            19.0.0
pyparsing            2.1.10
pyserial             3.1.1
PySocks              1.6.8
python-dateutil      2.6.1
python-dmidecode     3.12.2
python-linux-procfs  0.6.3
pytz                 2017.2
pyudev               0.21.0
PyYAML               3.12
requests             2.20.0
rpm                  4.14.3
schedutils           0.6
selinux              2.9
sepolicy             1.1
setools              4.3.0
setuptools           39.2.0
six                  1.11.0
subscription-manager 1.28.21
suds-jurko           0.7.dev0
syspurpose           1.28.21
typing_extensions    4.1.1
urllib3              1.24.2
userpath             1.7.0
virtualenv           20.13.2
virtualenv-clone     0.5.7
webencodings         0.5.1
zipp                 3.6.0
```

Following the README that the previous engineers wrote, I then do:

```
pipenv shell
```

Now if I do:

```
pip3 list
```

This is all that is installed:

```
pip        21.3.1
setuptools 59.6.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

So I run the install script again, a lot seems to get installed, mostly I see "Requirement already satisfied" and then I do this again:

```
pip3 list
```

but still:

```
pip        21.3.1
setuptools 59.6.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

Somehow the install script doesn't use the same path as `pipenv shell`.

I see this warning:

*WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead:*  *https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv*

I've a few questions. Doesn't `pipenv shell` establish a virtual environment? Is `venv` something I would need to do in addition to `pipenv shell`?

Also, even running as root, is there a way I can get all of the Python software to use the same path?

I'm looking for the simplest way to get this software running. This is just for development.

Comment: "5 engineers worked on this for years, but they have all left, and I'm trying to figure it out on my own"—the entire team abandoning this is not a good sign... be very wary of the product and / or the employer.

Comment: Unfortunately this question isn't going to be a good fit here. It is far too broad with too many unknowns. Just for starters, we have no idea what this mysterious "install script" does. Some tips, though: (a) _Don't_ run as root. There is never a good reason to do that for daily development tasks. (b) Learn how to use Pipenv. I really hope the install script leverages it under the hood, as managing dependencies is your dependency manager's job, not some arbitrary script's. (c) There's a good chance you shouldn't be developing on this machine at all. Dev locally, deploy to the server.

Comment: I tried to run this locally on my Mac but that was hopeless. The main version of the hasn't been updated in 3 years and the version conflicts were epic. But a year ago an engineer updated the install script for Centos8. Since Centos8 was EOL in December, I cannot use it, but Redhat8 is the same, so I set up an EC2 with Redhat8. This is the only possible way to make progress.